# How to get uplines of an id in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

| id | user_id | referral_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 4 | 1 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 |

When I query `where user_id = 5`, I would like to get the following:

| id | user_id | referral_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | null |
| 2 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 3 | 2 |
| 5 | 5 | 3 |

I'm using MySQL 5 so I can't use cte.
Edit: I need the parents for the id not the children.

Comment: No this works for going down not up the list

Comment: @stu That question's answer is flawed for truely generic path traversal.  This example shows that it breaks when children have lower `id`s that their parents : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/09ea61

Comment: @MatBailie there are 16 answers, which are you referring to?